# How to connect with 2ba it's API using PHP

Tags: php, api, oauth-2.0

Im trying to connect to the API services of [2ba](https://www.2ba.nl/documentatie/webservices). Somehow I just can't connect. I get the error: error: "invalid_client"

I dont know what to try, it feels like I need to hash my cliend_secret or complete url but I dont see that in the documentation.

This is my code (PHP):

```php
<?php

//  ---- GET TOKEN ----

// Base url for all api calls.
$baseURL = 'https://authorize.2ba.nl';

// Specified url endpoint. This comes after the baseUrl.
$endPoint = '/OAuth/Token';

// Parameters that are required or/and optianal for the endPoint its request.
$parameters = 'grant_type=password&username=abc@abc.com&password=123abc&client_id=myClientID&client_secret=myClientSecret';

// All parts together.
$url = $baseURL . $endPoint . '?' . $parameters;



//Init session for CURL.
$ch = curl_init();

// Options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');

// Init headers for access to the binance API signed data.
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
$headers[] = 'Content-Length: 0';

// Setting headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Execute request.
$data = curl_exec($ch);

// If there is an error. Show whats wrong.
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

// Ends the CURL session, frees all resources and deletes the curl (ch).
curl_close($ch);

$result = json_encode($data);

echo($data);
exit();

?>
```

The authentication is oauth2 and I want to use the "Password Grant" flow since I can login automaticly this way. Also I see in the [example code](https://www.2ba.nl/documentatie/webservices/oauth2/resource-owner-password-credentials-grant) in C# that they encode the url, something im not doing yet but did try. It did not work.

```php
// Using $encodedUrl like this: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $encodedUrl); but does not work.
$encodedUrl = urlencode($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I fixed it. I now got my access token and am able to recieve data from the API. This is what I did:

```php
//  ---- GET TOKEN - FLOW: USER PSW ----

// No changes
$baseURL = 'https://authorize.2ba.nl';

// No changes
$endPoint = '/OAuth/Token';

// $parameters is now an array.
$parameters = array(
    'grant_type'    => 'password',
    'username'      => 'myUsername',
    'password'      => 'myPassword',
    'client_id'     => 'myClientID',
    'client_secret' => 'myClientSecret'
);

// Removed the $parameter part
$url = $baseURL . $endPoint;

//Init session for CURL.
$ch = curl_init();

// Init headers for access to the binance API signed data.
$headers = array();
$headers['Content-Type'] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

// NOTE: http_build_query fixed it.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($parameters)); // Automaticly encodes parameters like client_secret and id.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

// Execute request.
$data = curl_exec($ch);

// If there is an error. Show whats wrong.
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

// Ends the CURL session, frees all resources and deletes the curl (ch).
curl_close($ch);

$result = json_encode($data);

echo($data);
exit();
```